# Using multiple values field in Lotus Notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I am trying to write a logging system for a form in Lotus Notes but I am at the part where I am not sure how I can append the information about the fields that are changed in the log fields. There are 3 fields that I use Log_Date (date), Log_User and Log_Actions (Text, allow multiple values).

I thought if I add comma to the log field it will create a new line when displaying the form but I am still getting a type mismatch on the case 2 line.

How can I append the new values to the log fields?

```
Sub Querysave(Source As Notesuidocument, Continue As Variant)
    ' Compare the values in the form after it is saved with its original values when the document is not a new document.    
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Set doc = Source.Document

    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim user As String
    user = session.CommonUserName

    If newDoc Then
        doc.Log_Date = Now()    
        doc.Log_User = user
        doc.Log_Actions = "New document created."
    Else        
        ' Load fields value to the array
        lastValues(0) = doc.QCR_No(0)
        lastValues(1) = doc.QCR_Mobile_Item_No(0)
        lastValues(2) = doc.QCR_Qty(0)

    ' Compared each value in the array to see if there is any difference
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To 2
            If lastValues(i) <> originalValues(i) Then
                Select  Case i
                Case 2 : doc.Log_Actions = doc.Log_Actions & "," & "Field QCR_Qty is changed"
                End Select
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

`doc.Log_Actions` returns the notesitem. To access the value you need to use `doc.Log_Actions(0)`

Comment: If he addresses it as Log_Actions(0) and doesn't change anything else in the code, then he will not be treating it as a multi-value item.  He will just be creating a single value with a comma-separated list.  This could result in strange behavior if he opens the document in the Notes UI, edits and saves it. I.e., if the field is set up as multi-value with a comma separator for display, the save operation will break it into multi values, and then the next time his code runs it will append to the first value again.

Comment: Absolutely true, I was only addressing the type mismatch error.

Answer (score 2):

In LotusScript back-end classes (e.g. NotesDocument, NotesItem), a multi-valued field is represented by an array with one value per element of the array.  For setting the value of a field, doc.Log_Actions is shorthand (they call it 'extended syntax' in the Domino Designer help) for assigning the first (i.e., zero subscript) element of the array, but that does not work for getting the value.  To get the first value, you have to use doc.Log_Actions(0).  To get or set the second value, you have to use doc.Log_Actions(1).

So, your Case 2 code could look like this:

```
doc.Log_Actions(1) = "Field QCR_Qty is changed"
```

My guess, however, is that you really want to be able to continually append to the end of the list of values each time this code runs.  You are also going to want your code to be robust and not blow up on you if (for any reason!) the Log_Actions item does not exist in the document.  For that, you are going to want to do this:

```
dim actionsItem as NotesItem
if doc.hasItem("Log_Actions") then
   set actionsItem = doc.getFirstItem("Log_Actions")
   call actionsItem.AppendToTextList("Field QCR_Qty is changed")
end if
```

Comment: Forgot to mention.. you're going to want an else clause that creates the missing NotesItem and then assigns the value to the 0th element.

Comment: It says: "setting the value of a field, doc.Log_Actions is shorthand ... for assigning the first (i.e., zero subscript) element of the array" - But I think that you can assign an entire array of values with doc.field = array and you will get a multivalue list assigned. If you only want a single value, then select it from the array (typically fist 0th element) doc.field = val(0)

Answer (score 1):

Or,

```
If (Not doc.HasItem("LogActions")) Then
  doc.LogActions = "Field QCR_Qty is changed"
Else
  doc.LogActions = ArrayAppend(doc.LogActions,"Field QCR_Qty is changed")
End If
```

This is equivalent to the `NotesItem` method by `rhsatrhs`, which you use is  matter of preference.

Comment: I like the arrayAppend twist - nice.